# How to return record with unconstrained 2d array from a function

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

I have a record type(`REC`) which contains an element of type `VECTOR` which is an unconstrained 2d array of `STD_LOGIC`:

```
package TEST is

    type VECTOR is array (NATURAL range <>, NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;

    type REC is record

        data : VECTOR;

    end record REC;

    function con(
        a : REC;
        b : REC)
        return REC;

end package TEST;
```

When declaring the body of the `con` function I want to specify the size of the `REC.data` array like so:

```
package body TEST is

    function con(
     a : REC;
     b : REC)
        return REC is variable r : REC(
            data(a.data'length(1) + b.data'length(1) - 1 downto 0, a.data'length(2) - 1 downto 0));

        begin

            -- . . . do things

    end function con;

end package body TEST;
```

but in the line where I attempt to set the size of data it Vivado throws the following error:

```
Sliced name is allowed only on single-dimensional arrays
```

Does this mean I cannot have an unconstrained 2d arraign in a record or is there a different method for defining the size of it in the `con` function ?

**---- EDIT ----**

Since I now understand that it is not possible to use 2d arrays in this context what method should I use to create a function which:

- Takes two 2d arrays (or arrays of arrays) of size [x][y] and [z][y] as inputs
- Outputs an array of size [x+z][y]
- With both input arrays being unconstrained and the output array being constrained to size [x+z][y]
- And all arrays (input and return) be a record type

Comment: VHDL does not allow slicing N dimensional arrays, only 1D arrays can be sliced. Any reason you made a 2D array of std_logic, and not a 1D array of std_logic_vector (that could be sliced)?

Comment: And are you sure the error points to the variable declaration? there is no slicing happening in your code example.

Comment: The error happens in line 7 of the second code snippet, and I am sure it is on that line because Vivado is highlighting the line. About using `std_logic_vector`, if I made `vector` a 1d array of unconstrained `std_logic_vector` that would work, I just don't know how I would rewrite my `con` function body return to make it work

Comment: If you have a way to achieve what i'm trying to do in my code snippets by making `VECTOR` a 1d array of  `std_logic_vector` instead of a 2d array of `std_logic` then that would be the solution to my problem :)

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do, other than create a record to store and and B

Comment: And here's the issue. The OP is trying to use a record constraint (found in -2008) to provide a constraint on element data which is multi-dimensional type VECTOR, all without a [mcve]. Understanding why [this works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKJBZ.jpg) should while away some time.

Comment: I added a EDIT destine to the bottom of my question, I hope that better describes what I am trying to achieve. The actual operation that the function does is not at question here, Im am just trying to figure out the neatest type for the input and output

Comment: @user1155120 I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to say. Are you saying my code is not a minimal reproducible example, because except for me forgetting to include the STD_LOGIC library the code reproduces the problem when I paste it into Vivado, and it is about as minimal as I can get it. Or are you saying that the code you linked as `this works` works for you, because at least in my Vivado it still throws the same error ?

Comment: @Mercury have you changed the filetype in Vivado to `VHDL-2008`? What Vivado version do you use?

Comment: I am using `Vivado 2020.1` with the target language for the project set to `VHDL`. Im not sure where I would look about the `VHDL-2008` I only started programming in VHDL last week and am not very familiar with Vivado

Comment: @Mercury when you add a (VHDL) file to Vivado, it's by default set to use VHDL 93, but not 2008. Go to the property Window and change the file type from `VHDL` to `VHDL 2008`. I'm not sure why it prints the wrong error message in your case. (Vivado likes to confuse users with wrong error messages ...). Anyhow, it should have reported your feature is only supported in 2008 mode.

Comment: @Paebbels Thank you, that fixed the problem, maybe add it as a sub note to your response so I can mark it as accepted answer. You just saved me hours of frustration. And I'm already getting familiar with Vivado's shenanigans, my Favorit one of which is "ERROR close to ..." which has to be one of the most useless error messages I have experience in a long time :)

Comment: Added the hint for 2008 to my answer.

Comment: Rather than a two dimensional array, it is common to use a one dimensional array whose element type is an array, here std_logic_vector.   An array of an array can be sliced.   Interestingly, you will find some synthesis tools weak on their support of two dimensional arrays.   If you re-read @Tricky 's first comment you will see that in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user1155120 I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to say. Are you saying my code is not
a minimal reproducible example, because except for me forgetting to include the STD_LOGIC library
the code reproduces the problem when I paste it into Vivado, and it is about as minimal as I can get it.
Or are you saying that the code you linked as this works works for you, because at least in my
Vivado it still throws the same error ? – Mercury 4 hours ago
```

The original comment was meant for Tricky. There's a missing return statement in the function `con` which would prevent use in an example.

It isn't clear if record constraints (a -2008 feature) are supported in Vivado Simulator. In Vivado Synthesis Guide UG901 2020.1 we see all sorts of wonderful uses of record types from everything to inferring ram to record elements of record types. Xilinx has been busy.

It'd seems odd if unconstrained elements in record type declarations were supported but not record constraints (they're pretty much a package deal, pun aside). Note the comment called it a -2008 feature.

A record constraint is limited to supply the constraint of an element or subelement that is of an unconstrained type (typically arrays). VHDL has always been capable of supplying multi-dimensional array constraints. The language of the standard is particular based on the flexibility of the syntax.

This code is VHDL -2008 compliant and provides your record constraint:

```vhdl
library ieee;                  -- ADDED for MCVe
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;   -- ADDED

package TEST is
    type VECTOR is array (NATURAL range <>, NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;

    type REC is record
        data: VECTOR;
    end record REC;
    
    function con (a: REC; b: REC) return REC;
end package TEST;

package body TEST is
    function con (a: REC; b: REC) return REC is 
        variable r: 
            REC (         -- record constraint:
              data (
                natural range a.data'length(1) + b.data'length(1) - 1 downto 0,
                natural range a.data'length(2) - 1 downto 0
              )
          );
    begin
        -- . . . do things 
        return r;     -- ADDED required return statement
    end function con;
end package body TEST;
```

You'll note the changes to the record constraint from yours is the addition of `natural range` before each range of the element data constraint.

From IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.3 Record types:

> record_constraint ::=
>     ( record_element_constraint { , record_element_constraint } )
>
> record_element_constraint ::= *record_element*_simple_name element_constraint

From 6.3 Subtype declarations:

> element_constraint ::=
>       array_constraint
>     | record_constraint

Here the element data is an array so an array_constraint is appropriate.

From 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1:

array_constraint ::=

> index_constraint [ array_element_constraint ]
>     | ( **open** ) [ array_element_constraint ]

Because element data array elements are scalar (enumeration type STD_LOGIC) we follow index_constraint.

> index_constraint ::= ( discrete_range { , discrete_range } )
>
> discrete_range ::= *discrete*_subtype_indication | range

The code shown above uses a discrete subtype indication for the index ranges of the element data dimensions and successfully analyzes (compiles).

From 5.2.2 Scalar types, 5.2.2.1:

> range ::=
>       range_attribute_name
>     | simple_expression direction simple_expression
>
> direction ::= **to** | **downto**

The constraint in the question uses a range with simple expressions and direction.

So why did it produce the error message about multi-dimensional slices?

In 9. Expressions, 9.1 the BNF, simple_expression -> term -> factor -> primary -> name.

In 8. Names, 8.1 name -> slice_name, only multi-dimensional slices are not allowed semantically in 8.5 Slice names who's BNF tells us it's syntactically valid:

> slice_name ::= prefix ( discrete_range )
>
> The prefix of a slice shall be appropriate for a one-dimensional array object. The base type of this array type is the type of the slice.

and semantically the prefix `data` is not appropriate for a one-dimensional array object.

These comments provide bit more context for the problem although it isn't clear which version the record constraint you used in the reported eventual success:

```
@Mercury when you add a (VHDL) file to Vivado, it's by default set to use VHDL 93, but not 2008. Go
to the property Window and change the file type from VHDL to VHDL 2008. I'm not sure why it
prints the wrong error message in your case. (Vivado likes to confuse users with wrong error messages
...). Anyhow, it should have reported your feature is only supported in 2008 mode. – Paebbels 3 hours
ago

@Paebbels Thank you, that fixed the problem, maybe add it as a sub note to your response so I can
mark it as accepted answer. You just saved me hours of frustration. And I'm already getting familiar with
Vivado's shenanigans, my Favorit one of which is "ERROR close to ..." which has to be one of the most
useless error messages I have experience in a long time :) – Mercury 3 hours ago
```

As far as detecting -2008 source, there are no -1993 syntax errors and no -2008 new reserved word, delimiters, separators or graphics characters in either the primary unit or the secondary.

That leaves you at the mercy of semantic analysis which failed. You could also note the unconstrained record element wasn't reported during analysis of the package declaration. It occurred during evaluation of the variable `r`. All declared objects are required to be constrained. VHDL doesn't have a recital of all features, semantics can be restrictive as well. It's legal in places to have unconstrained elements and objects.

Associating semantics rules found in the text of the standard with an textual element of the particular declaration or statement can be tough and the squeaky wheel gets the lubricant. Record constraints are relatively new to VHDL implementations.

The problem appears to have been one of tool familiarity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive reply, I now see that your first comment contained the solution, it was just not very understandable. As a sort of follow up I would like to ask if there is any way of denoting in the files comets itself to use `VHDL-2008` so that if I ever use this file somewhere else I won't have to specify it again in the IDE ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition of row and column merges from [PoC's](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) [vectors package](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/vectors.vhdl?ts=2), see [lines starting at 359](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/vectors.vhdl?ts=2#L359):

```vhdl
    function slm_merge_rows(slm1 : T_SLM; slm2 : T_SLM) return T_SLM is
        constant ROWS     : positive    := slm1'length(1) + slm2'length(1);
        constant COLUMNS  : positive    := slm1'length(2);
        variable slm      : T_SLM(ROWS - 1 downto 0, COLUMNS - 1 downto 0);
    begin
        for i in slm1'range(1) loop
            for j in slm1'low(2) to slm1'high(2) loop         -- WORKAROUND: Xilinx iSIM work-around, because 'range(2) evaluates to 'range(1); see work-around notes at T_SLM type declaration
                slm(i, j)   := slm1(i, j);
            end loop;
        end loop;
        for i in slm2'range(1) loop
            for j in slm2'low(2) to slm2'high(2) loop         -- WORKAROUND: Xilinx iSIM work-around, because 'range(2) evaluates to 'range(1); see work-around notes at T_SLM type declaration
                slm(slm1'length(1) + i, j)    := slm2(i, j);
            end loop;
        end loop;
        return slm;
    end function;

    function slm_merge_cols(slm1 : T_SLM; slm2 : T_SLM) return T_SLM is
        constant ROWS     : positive    := slm1'length(1);
        constant COLUMNS  : positive    := slm1'length(2) + slm2'length(2);
        variable slm      : T_SLM(ROWS - 1 downto 0, COLUMNS - 1 downto 0);
    begin
        for i in slm1'range(1) loop
            for j in slm1'low(2) to slm1'high(2) loop         -- WORKAROUND: Xilinx iSIM work-around, because 'range(2) evaluates to 'range(1); see work-around notes at T_SLM type declaration
                slm(i, j)   := slm1(i, j);
            end loop;
            for j in slm2'low(2) to slm2'high(2) loop         -- WORKAROUND: Xilinx iSIM work-around, because 'range(2) evaluates to 'range(1); see work-around notes at T_SLM type declaration
                slm(i, slm1'length(2) + j)    := slm2(i, j);
            end loop;
        end loop;
        return slm;
    end function;
```

The definition of `T_SLM` is:

```vhdl
type T_SLM is array(natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;
```

Currently, I see no problem in nesting this code in another layer like your unconstrained record.

---

**Edit:**

Thie code above requires VHDL 2008 to be enabled in Vivado.

> When VHDL files are added to Vivado, it's by default set to use VHDL 93, but not 2008. Go to the property Window and change the file type from `VHDL` to VHDL 2008``.
> The printed error message is misleading and points to a false feature being used. The correct message should be it's a VHDL-2008 feature, please enable it.

Comment: This is essentially what I want to do except for having `T_SLM` being an element within a record, the problem is that as soon as I package `T_SLM` in a record this line `variable slm : T_SLM(ROWS - 1 downto 0, COLUMNS - 1 downto 0);` ends up looking like this `variable slm : REC(dat(ROWS - 1 downto 0, COLUMNS - 1 downto 0));` where dat is an element of type `T_SLM` in record `REC` and this ends up throwing the same error because it is synonymous with my original code. Or I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to demonstrate

Comment: So this code would for fill the first 3 of the bullet points in my **EDIT** section but as soon as we introduce `T_SLM` into a record and use the recored instead of `T_SLM` directly we end up with the same problem of the not being able to constrain the 2d array in the function return